# Proper Way to Append Class & AJAX Call

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, so I really don't think I'm structuring my JS properly, and am hoping someone can point me in the right direction. I don't think sequentially naming the classes for each list item is an effective, or proper way of accomplishing this.

I have a list of checkboxes that, when clicked, need to perform two actions:

1) Toggle the class name of a div located directly below it.

2) Post via AJAX the state.

**Here is my current markup:**

```
<ol class="toolkitList">
<li>
            <label><input class="inlineCheckers" type="checkbox" id="checkers" onchange="setCheck();" /><b id="grayTitle">List Title 1</b></label>
                <i id="hiddenDiv">Div content can go here.</i>
        </li>

        <li>
            <label><input class="inlineCheckers" type="checkbox" id="checkers2" onchange="setCheck2();" /><b id="grayTitle2">List title 2</b></label>
                <i id="hiddenDiv2">Div content can go here.</i>
        </li>

        <li>
            <label><input class="inlineCheckers" type="checkbox" id="checkers3" onchange="setCheck3();" /><b id="grayTitle3">List title 3</b></label>
                <i id="hiddenDiv3">Div content can go here.</i>
        </li>

        <li>
            <label><input class="inlineCheckers" type="checkbox" id="checkers4" onchange="setCheck4();" /><b id="grayTitle4">List Title 4</b></label>
                <i id="hiddenDiv4">Div content can go here.</i>
        </li>
    </ol>
```

**Here is my current JS:**

```
function setCheck() {
var el = document.getElementById("checkers");

if (el.checked) {
    document.getElementById("hiddenDiv").className = "main";
    document.getElementById("grayTitle").className = "titleGray";
 } else {
    document.getElementById("hiddenDiv").className = "";
    document.getElementById("grayTitle").className = "";
 }
}

function setCheck2() {
var el2 = document.getElementById("checkers2");

if (el2.checked) {
    document.getElementById("hiddenDiv2").className = "main";
    document.getElementById("grayTitle2").className = "titleGray";
 } else {
    document.getElementById("hiddenDiv2").className = "";
    document.getElementById("grayTitle2").className = "";
 }
}

function setCheck3() {
var el3 = document.getElementById("checkers3");

if (el3.checked) {
    document.getElementById("hiddenDiv3").className = "main";
    document.getElementById("grayTitle3").className = "titleGray";
 } else {
    document.getElementById("hiddenDiv3").className = "";
    document.getElementById("grayTitle3").className = "";
 }
}

function setCheck4() {
var el4 = document.getElementById("checkers4");

if (el4.checked) {
    document.getElementById("hiddenDiv4").className = "main";
    document.getElementById("grayTitle4").className = "titleGray";
 } else {
    document.getElementById("hiddenDiv4").className = "";
    document.getElementById("grayTitle4").className = "";
 }
}
```

I realize I don't have the AJAX portion of this setup yet, but I wanted to make that requirement known, as I will be adding that part into the code shortly. Thanks for any guidance you can provide!

Comment: Why the code repetition? The idea of functions is to be able to re-use the same function for different contexts.

Comment: Also, jQuery makes it easy do bind the event handlers dynamically, so that you don't have to hard code stuff like `onchange="..."`.

Comment: Thats my question exactly - how do I implement that?

Comment: Btw, consider avoiding words like "gray" and "Div" in your class names. You might want to change colors, or element types subsequently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also apply the class to outer div

CSS:

```
.selected label b {
    color:blue
}
.selected i {
    color:red
}
```

JS:

```
$(".inlineCheckers").on('click',function(){
    $(this).parents("li").toggleClass('selected',$(this).is(":checked"));
})
```

jsfiddle  :  http://jsfiddle.net/y2rHF/3/

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would do it:

```
$toolkitlist.on( 'change', '.inlineCheckers', function () {
    $( this ).closest( 'li' ).toggleClass( 'checked', this.checked );
});
```

where `$toolkitlist` is a jQuery object containing the OL element. Notice how I set the class on the LI element, because that is the outermost element which represents the checked item. You can use these selectors to style the "checked" states:

```
/* how they look like initially */
.grayTitle { ... }
.hiddenDiv { ... }

/* how they look like when their check-box is checked */
li.checked .grayTitle { ... }
li.checked .hiddenDiv { ... }
```

Comment: You're initial code throws a syntax error. Line 1 after 'change'

Comment: @viablepath My initial code was syntactically invalid. Try the latest code.

Comment: As long as there is only one input inside the li I'd listen to a change of 'input' instead of '.inlineCheckers' for performance reasons (i know that it normally will be a very small impact, but... an impact! ;). Apart of that this is exactly what i'd do.

Comment: I like your version of the code Sime - it's clear and to the point, but I'm getting an undefined error on $toolkitlist? I'm a newb, so I apologize if this is a basic thing that I should be aware of...Thanks for your help!

Comment: @viablepath In order for my code to work, you have to manually set up the `$toolkitlist` variable. The simplest method would be `var $toolkitlist = $( '.toolkitlist' );`. You *could* write `$( '.toolkitlist' ).on( 'change', ...` directly, but I prefer to do the DOM queries separately on page init (usually, the DOM ready event), so that I have the references to all the relevant static elements cached in variables.

Answer (score 2):

use jQuery's [**`addClass`**](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

```
$('#grayTitle3').addClass('titleGray');
```

Update, using [**`^=`**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$('[id^=grayTitle]').addClass('titleGray');
```

Comment: That's not the issue. My question is - how can I add the class to different divs & checkboxes without having to rename the ID's and functions (setCheck1, setCheck2, ect). That seems like a wasteful way of approaching it.

Answer (score 1):

remove the inline .onchange.. and bind the change event to your class `.inlineCheckers - then you can use`this` so you don't have to make multiple functions for each set

```
$('.inlineCheckers').on('change', function {
  $el = $(this);
  var $hd = $el.closest('label').next('i'); 
  var $gt = $el.next('b');
  $hd.toggleClass('main', $el[0].checked);
  $gt.toggleClass('checkers', $el[0].checked);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KYzgB/